# Can't Update Image Src in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, image

I am trying to create a profile picture function for my website. The file upload and image display functions are working properly, however, it won't update the "profile" column in my table to the image name.

My database name is "intranet" and the table name is "profile". Here is my source code:

```
<?php session_start();
    $_SESSION['username'];
?>

<?php
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
            move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'],"images/profile/".$_FILES['file']['name']);
            $con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","intranet");
            $q = mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE user SET profile = '".$_FILES['file']['name']."' WHERE username = '".$_SESSION['username']."'");
    }
?>

 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>

    </head>
    <body>
            <form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    <input type="file" name="file">
                    <input type="submit" name="submit">
            </form>


            <?php
                    $con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","intranet");
                    $q = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM user");
                    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($q)){
                            echo $row['Username'];
                            if($row['profile'] == ""){
                                    echo "<img width='100' height='100' src='images/profile/default.jpg' alt='Default Profile Pic'>";
                            } else {
                                    echo "<img width='100' height='100' src='images/profile/".$row['image']."' alt='Profile Pic'>";
                            }
                            echo "<br>";
                    }
            ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you tried printing the query out in plaintext? Does it match expectations?

Comment: No, what exactly do you mean? Sorry, I am new to this.

Comment: No worries. You have an `UPDATE` statement. Instead of passing that through to `mysqli_query()` can you simply `echo` it? Check to see if the query matches what you expect it to be.

Comment: You need to add error handling. For example to the file upload section and all the database calls.

Comment: Would the problem have anything to do with the session?

Comment: It's because you're not connecting above it. Place your connection code seperately and above everything.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I placed the connection at the top of the page

Comment: @Fred-ii- My bad, didn't mean to hit enter, anyways still won't update.

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening PHP tag 
for example `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` then the rest of your code, to see if it yields anything, 
 as well as `or die(mysqli_error($con))` to `mysqli_query()`.

Comment: Did you echo your query statement to see that it is what you expect it to be as suggested by @MariM? I can't imagine from what you have that it won't be what you expect, but you never know.

Comment: @MariM I'm not exactly sure how to do that.

Comment: @user2812059 `echo "UPDATE user SET profile = '".$_FILES['file']['name']."' WHERE username = '".$_SESSION['username']."'";`

Comment: @MariM I got this result from running the "echo"    Notice: Undefined index: username in C:\IntranetBeta\test.php on line 9
UPDATE user SET profile = 'Koala.jpg' WHERE username = ''

Comment: are you sure it's not updating the `profile` column? At the bottom you use `$row['image']` instead of `$row['profile']`... could that be it?

Comment: That's because you're not doing anything with this `$_SESSION['username'];` it's just sitting on that one line as `$_SESSION['username'];` instead of `$_SESSION['username'] = "John Doe";` as an example. Which is going to make it that much more harder to know how it's supposed to be assigned as, or if it's being assigned somewhere else.

Comment: @user2812059 That indicates to me that your `$_SESSION` is not set correctly, as `username` does not exist as a key in it. I would recommend taking a look into that first and foremost.

Comment: @RightClick I didn't even notice that, although it didn't solve my immidiate problem it definately needed to be changed.

Comment: @MariM What should I do with the session?

Comment: @RightClick what row are you talking about? image? or do you mean the row profile? profile is there, however it is empty.

Comment: Take a look below at the answer from @Fred-ii-

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *"I got this result from running the "echo" Notice: Undefined index: username in C:\IntranetBeta\test.php on line 9 UPDATE user SET profile = 'Koala.jpg' WHERE username = ''"*

This block of code:

```
<?php session_start();
    $_SESSION['username'];
?>
```

Nothing is assigned to that session array, therefore you will need to assign it to something.

If it's coming from a previous page and is assigned there, then you will need to check if it's set and what it's assigned to.

Otherwise, you will need to either remove it or assign something to it.

I.e.:

```
<?php 
session_start();

    if(isset($_SESSION['username'])){
        $_SESSION['username'] = "John Doe";
        }

    else{
        $_SESSION['username'] = "Empty";
        }
?>
```

---

Plus, as I noted in comments earlier to place your connection first before trying to query.

- *"It's because you're not connecting above it. Place your connection code seperately and above everything."*

Comment: On a side note, I think you have a good point on moving the connection outside (I doesn't solve the issue, I'm sure, but it makes for a better code I think!). Especially since the OP uses it for the select down the page. No need to be redundant.

Comment: @Rasclatt True, which I did mention in an earlier comment to them under their question.

Comment: Yeah that's what I am referring to. They should do that as-per your comment.

Comment: That fixed it! Thank you very much. Quick question, if the name in the "if" session is set to a specific username (i.e John Doe), will this only work for that user?

Comment: @user2812059 You're welcome. Well, it will depend on which user you want to assign the session array to. There are many ways of doing it, from a POST array from a previous form, or fetched from DB. That is up to you.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Ok, that makes sense, and thank you everyone for the help

Answer (score 0):

Check if the profile field is a varchar, or check if there is already an image with the same name in the images/profile folder. If so, try to generate a unique file name before moving the uploaded file .

Comment: The profile field is a varchar and the file name is unique inside the profile folder